# How to make column values that are the result of JSON column formatting available in list export and filtering?

Tags: sharepoint-online, microsoft-lists

I have created two columns of type `Single line of text`.

They reference a `Person` column via the following JSON column formatting:

**Department**

```
{
  "$schema": "https://developer.microsoft.com/json-schemas/sp/v2/column-formatting.schema.json",
  "elmType": "div",
  "txtContent": "[$Author.department]"
}
```

**Job Title**

```
{
  "$schema": "https://developer.microsoft.com/json-schemas/sp/v2/column-formatting.schema.json",
  "elmType": "div",
  "txtContent": "[$Author.jobTitle]"
}
```

I get the desired behaviour of being able to see the following in the list:

```
Person Name  |  Business Department  |  Job Title
```

However, the following undesired behaviors are occurring:

- Exported list has no values in the `Department` or `Job Title` columns
- There are no values in the `Department` or `Job Title` section that I can filter on

I understand why this is happening (because the JSON formatting is grabbing values after the data has loaded - and it is just formatting, not *real* data), but I am just wondering if there are any approaches to getting the desired behaviour working? i.e being able to export and filter on the `Department` and `Job Title` values.

I thought about using a `Calculated Column` to reference the properties of the `Person` column, but `Person` is not supported.

Answer (score 1):

You could create a Power Automate flow as a workaround: when an item is created get "Department" and "Job Title" value from person column then set value to Single line of text columns.

Here is article about [Getting SharePoint field values in Power Automate](https://sharepains.com/2018/04/20/sharepoint-field-values-power-automate/) for reference.

Comment: Is there any update on this thread? Comment here if you still need any help